# SQL select ids like unique tag

Tags: sql, postgresql

Each id in my table has an tags column where the text are comma separated strings like
Biology,Life sciences,Organisms,Biotechnology

I am using this query to select all the ids that are like the tag "carbon".

```
SELECT f.id 
FROM   ttrss_user_entries e 
INNER JOIN ttrss_entries f 
ON f.id = e.ref_id 
WHERE e.tags_new LIKE '%carbon%'
```

The problem is that because there are also tags like "carbon dioxide", there are duplicate ids.

Is there a way to select ids that match *only* the text between single quotes?

The above query returns

```
3362   │ Polycyclic aromatic hydrocarbon,Nature
69984  │ Low-carbon economy,Renewable Energy
444573 │ Fluorocarbon,Magnesium
5637   │ Carbon,Fossil
```

but I want it to return

```
5637 │ Carbon,Fossil
```

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Use `=` instead of `LIKE`

Comment: I am using Postgres

Comment: `',' || e.tags_new || ',' LIKE '%,cell,%'`

Comment: check this: [Postgresql Pattern Matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: replace your WHERE to this one `e.tags_new ANY (string_to_array('cell')::text[])` this should work

Comment: Not sure it it works in postgresql. If it was MySQL I'd use 

`SELECT f.id 
FROM   ttrss_user_entries e 
INNER JOIN ttrss_entries f 
ON f.id = e.ref_id 
WHERE e.tags_new LIKE BINARY '%Carbon%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your data structure!  Don't store tags in a delimited string.  One option in Postgres is as an array.  Another is as a separate table with one row per entry and tag (the traditional approach).

Here is how the array solution would look:

```
WHERE 'carbon' = any (regexp_split_to_array(e.tags_new, ','::text)
```

I would suggest that you change the data format so the column is an array.

Comment: Thanks! I just needed a close bracket at the end. It looks like the search text is case sensitive too. Is there an easy way to convert the text column to a text[]  column?